# Unable to apply Daylight Savings changes in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

I am trying to solve a problem with Daylight Savings.  The code will be running on Windows XP embedded under .net 2.0 fw.  I have everything working except one small problem.  The requirement is to programmatically set the Daylight Savings setting in the TimeDate.cpl panel which is just the window where you set date and time.  The only way I have found to do this is by creating a registry entry and this does work.  However, it doesn't take affect until you physically open the TimeDate window, click on the timezone panel and hit apply.  Not even a reboot will do it.  My question is this:  Is there a way to have my C# application open the TimeDate windows and click apply?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, because you're doing it wrong in the first place. :-)

<strike>The proper way to do it is to use the API function [`SetDaylightTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488917%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx), which accepts a parameter indicating whether or not daylight savings is in effect in the local timezone.</strike> The referenced function above is not available on XP Embedded, apparently. The remainder is valid, AFAIK.

For using the registry, you don't need the TimeDate control panel applet; you can do it directly in code using the code sample in [Daylight Saving Time Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488379%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) as an example. Notice the calls to `RegFlushKey` in the code; they make the changes persistent. Also note that it mentions that the change is effect on the next reboot, not immediately; that's the way WinXP desktop (and Vista/Win7, too, IIRC)  works as well.

Comment: That is what I'm using to set the time zone.  I am unclear as to whether or not this allows you to toggle Daylight Savings.

Comment: Sorry; I don't know which version of my answer you're citing. (I posted an incorrect one first, and then posted this corrected version with `SetDaylightTime`.) If it's the `SetDaylightTime` answer, the documentation specifically says that the purpose of the function is to indicate whether Daylight Savings is in effect or not; Windows will adjust the time from UTC accordingly as needed.

Comment: The RegFlushKey call looks promising.  I'm trying to port it over to c# so I can test it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `SetDaylightTime` takes care of setting up the registry and flushing changes for you automatically; that's what it's there for (see the first boxed note on the registry settings page I linked above).

Comment: I tried it(SetDaylightTime) and got "Unable to load dll Coredll".  This api is listed under CE.  Are you sure it's good under XP.

Comment: According to the link, it says it's available in CE 2.0 and above for Embedded (see the bottom of the docs link for `SetDaylightTime`). According to your question, you're using v2. I don't have an XP Embedded system to test on to help you work this out, though. :-(

Comment: I'm running .net 2.0 not CE 2.0.  Reading shows that coredll.dll is not available on xp.

Comment: I edited my question to remove the `SetDaylightTime` portion, since that's not available on your target OS. The info on writing to the registry should still apply, however, AFAICT.